# Can you solve $X A X^T = B$ for $X$ over Gaussian rationals in GAP?

Tags: quadratic-forms, gap, computer-algebra-systems

I have two symmetric matrices : $A$ is $a \times a$ and $B$ is $b \times b$. I'm trying to find solutions for $X A X^T = B$. $A$ and $B$ are constant and $X$ is the unknown $b \times a$ matrix. All matrices are over the Gaussian rationals, CF(4) in GAP. Is this doable in GAP or any of its packages?